# How to interpolate semilogx plot with cubic spline or pchip

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

So I have been stuck on this for a while. I am wondering how to interpolate on a semilogx plot using different methods like pchip or cubic spline. So far this is the code that I have.

```
from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0.425, 100],
        [0.18, 96],
        [0.090, 85],
        [0.075, 80],
        [0.04, 59],
        [0.02, 39],
        [0.01, 26],
        [0.005, 15],
        [0.0015, 8]]
data = np.array(data)

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

x = np.flip(x)
y = np.flip(y)

interp_obj = PchipInterpolator(x, y)

new_x_vals = np.arange(0.0015, 0.42501, 0.0001)
new_y_vals = interp_obj(new_x_vals)

plt.semilogx(new_x_vals, new_y_vals)
plt.xlabel("Particle Diameter (mm) - Log Scale")
plt.ylabel("Percent Finer")

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

It seems as though this is not as smooth as a it should be. Should I be transforming the data before interpolation?

Comment: The docs state that:

    ""The first derivatives are guaranteed to be continuous, but the second
derivatives may jump at :math:`x_k`.""

You can have non smooth sections. If all you want is to plot it smoothly, use a regular `UnivariateSpline` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be transforming the data before interpolation?

Yes, certainly! You have to make sure the samples are logarithmically spaced. Linearly spaced samples on a logarithmic axis squeeze together on the right side of the plot together and pull apart on the left side.

Furthermore, I think the log-x-plot makes the cubic interpolation look linear-ish in log space, which is the effect you are actually observing.

If you log-transform the x values before interpolation

```
interp_obj = PchipInterpolator(np.log10(x), y)

new_x_vals = np.arange(0.0015, 0.42501, 0.0001)
new_y_vals = interp_obj(np.log10(new_x_vals))
```

you get this result:

[image]

Comment: That makes more sense! I was trying to transform it and then turn it back into normal space or something strange like that and it was just looking weird.